Set up OpenVPN to allow server access AND internet access
I have a server that hosts virtual clients (KVM). My virtual network uses the IP range 192.168.122.0/16, which means I want to communicate with addresses in the range 192.168.x.y.
Now I am installing OpenVPN and want to configure it so that VPN clients receive IP addresses in the range 192.168.123.x/16.
I want my VPN clients to have access to my virtual network (192.168.122.x) and to the internet.
How should I structure the /etc/openvpn/server.conf file and the firewall rules?

That's the default behavior, unless you have deliberately restricted traffic using firewall rules. There is no special configuration otherwise.
However, your networks overlap – both "192.168.122.0/16" and "192.168.123.x/16" are parts of the same 192.168.0.0/16. So if you actually have that IP configuration (i.e. if you're using 255.255.0.0 as netmask) in both OpenVPN and the KVM virtual network, then you have two network interfaces with overlapping configuration, which will lead to one or the other interface being chosen for all of 192.168.x.x/16.
Rearranging the IP addresses so that they don't overlap (in your case it seems like they should have been /24's) should make all communications work by default.

So what you're saying is that I need to set my virt network as 192.168.122.0/24 and VPN network as 192.168.123.0/24? Well... I was there... didn't work to me, but maybe I have sat something wrongly. Another question would be if my VPN client had routing set as so it would know to push 192.168.122.x into the VPN interface.

As for now I've sat (in server.conf)
server 192.168.123.0 255.255.255.0
Crazy enough, my clients get IP 192.168.123.x/255.255.255.254
... no matter what I do... How should server.conf look like?

That's what I'm saying, yes. You can push an additional 192.168.0.0/16 route to the VPN clients, but interface configurations must not overlap, no matter what type of network it is (the same applies to ethernet, dial-up, VPN, anything).

You're probably using an older OpenVPN that did default to "topology net30"? It should have no effect on the final result (and the problem I mentioned is on the server side interface anyway), but you can specify topology subnet (above 'server') to make clients see a more conventional config on their side.
